# Pandas write variable number of new rows from list in Series

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using `Pandas` as a way to write data from `Selenium`.

Two example results from a search box `ac_results` on a webpage:

```
#Search for product_id = "01"
ac_results = "Orange (10)"

#Search for product_id = "02"
ac_result = ["Banana (10)", "Banana (20)", "Banana (30)"]
```

Orange returns only one price ($10) while Banana returns a variable number of prices from different vendors, in this example three prices ($10), ($20), ($30).

The code uses regex via `re.findall` to grab each price and put them into a list. The code works fine as long as `re.findall` finds only one list item, as for Oranges. 
Problem is when there are a variable amount of prices, as when searching for Bananas. I would like to create a new row for each stated price, and the rows should also include `product_id` and `item_name`.

Current output:

```
product_id      prices                  item_name
01              10                      Orange
02              [u'10', u'20', u'30']   Banana
```

Desired output:

```
product_id      prices                  item_name
01              10                      Orange
02              10                      Banana
02              20                      Banana
02              30                      Banana
```

Current code:

```
df = pd.read_csv("product_id.csv")
def crawl(product_id):
    #Enter search input here, omitted
    #Getting results:
    search_result = driver.find_element_by_class_name("ac_results")
    item_name = re.match("^.*(?=(\())", search_result.text).group().encode("utf-8")
    prices = re.findall("((?<=\()[0-9]*)", search_reply.text)
    return pd.Series([prices, item_name])

df[["prices", "item_name"]] = df["product_id"].apply(crawl)
df.to_csv("write.csv", index=False)
```

FYI: Workable solution with `csv` module, but I want to use `Pandas`.

```
with open("write.csv", "a") as data_write:
    wr_data = csv.writer(data_write, delimiter = ",")
    for price in prices: #<-- This is the important part!
        wr_insref.writerow([product_id, price, item_name])
```

Comment: Basically all I need to do is the pandas equivalent of  `csv` module: 
    `for price in prices:
        wr_insref.writerow([product_id, price, item_name])` (see above). That means duplicating values from cols `product_id` and ìtem_name` as long as there are items in list `prices`.

Comment: I retrieve `prices` via re.findall as a list from an active search box. It shouldn't write the whole list to the cell however, which it is doing right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# initializing here for reproducibility
pids = ['01','02']
prices = [10, [u'10', u'20', u'30']]
names = ['Orange','Banana']
df = pd.DataFrame({"product_id": pids, "prices": prices, "item_name": names})
```

The following snippet should work after your `apply(crawl)`.

```
# convert all of the prices to lists (even if they only have one element)
df.prices = df.prices.apply(lambda x: x if isinstance(x, list) else [x])

# Create a new dataframe which splits the lists into separate columns.
# Then flatten using stack. The explicit MultiIndex allows us to keep
# the item_name and product_id associated with each price.
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(zip(*[df['item_name'],df['product_id']]), 
                                names = ['item_name', 'product_id'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df.prices.tolist(), index=idx).stack()

# drop the hierarchical index and select columns of interest
df2 = df2.reset_index()[['product_id', 0, 'item_name']]
# rename back to prices
df2.columns = ['product_id', 'prices', 'item_name']
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I will attempt to implement this but there may be a few hickups. Firstly I get `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'prices'`. Note that I'm getting `prices` not by manually entering it into `df` but by: `prices = re.findall("((?<=\()[0-9]*)", ac_result.text)` from webpage.

Comment: Also, is it possible to combine all of this with `def crawl(product_id):` and `df[["prices", "item_name"]] = df["product_id"].apply(crawl)` as displayed in the question? `Product_id` is retrieved from `df = pd.read_csv("product_id.csv")`.

Comment: I'm starting from `df` as defined in the second-to-last line of your code, after you've already done `df[["prices", "item_name"]] = df["product_id"].apply(crawl)`. My solution should work from there. You could probably modify `crawl` directly, but I won't attempt to do that because I don't have access to the same query data as you.

Comment: Ah okay, yes that makes sense. After implementing it after `crawl`, I get error: `df = pd.DataFrame({"product_id": pids, "prices": prices, "item_name": names})
NameError: name 'pids' is not defined`. I have tried to play around with possible explanations to this but can't find it atm.

Comment: You don't need to create `df` -- you already created it. I just included those first few lines so that my code snippet would be reproducible for other people. You should start with line 5 of my sample code.

Comment: Thanks! This is working now. I had to do `df["Prices"]` instead of `df.prices` however because that gave me the error: `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'prices'`. Thanks again, will reward bounty when the site allows me in 10 hrs.

Comment: `prices` is lowercase everywhere in your sample code. Either you didn't copy it correctly into Stack Overflow or you've changed it somewhere else.

Comment: That might be it, thanks. BTW I have a slight follow-up question, if I want to do `re.findall(r"(.*?)\((\d+)\)$", search_reply.text)` that gets multiple `names` for the same `product_id`, is there a way to have it write that instead of just the single name?

Comment: E.g. `[{"price":10, "product_id":2, "item_name":"yellow banana"}, {"price":5, "product_id":2, "item_name":"green banana"}]`

Comment: That's a pure Python/regex question that deserves its own question. I don't know the answer of the top of my head.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to run your code (probably missing inputs) but you can probably transform your `prices` list in a list of dict and then build a `DataFrame` from there:

```
 d = [{"price":10, "product_id":2, "item_name":"banana"}, 
      {"price":20, "product_id":2, "item_name":"banana"}, 
      {"price":10, "product_id":1, "item_name":"orange"}]
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Then `df` is:

```
  item_name  price  product_id
0    banana     10           2
1    banana     20           2
2    orange     10           1
```

Comment: Thanks, but bananas and oranges here are just examples. In reality, it will be any possible name and price, so I can't create a dictionary for it.