# Pandas: Insert variable substrings into column B from column A with help of dictionary

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas

I have this `pandas` dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(["LONG AAPL 2X CBZ","SHORT GOOG 10X VON"], columns=["Name"])
```

I would like to identify `"AAPL"` in column `Name`, pass that through a dictionary `"AAPL":"Apple"` and then insert that into a string in new column `Description`.

Desired output:

```
Name                   Description
"LONG AAPL 2X CBZ"     "Tracks Apple with 2X leverage."
"SHORT GOOG 10X VON"   "Tracks Google with -10X leverage."
```

The part where I'm having the problem is entering a variable substring into another string as `"Tracks X with Y leverage."`

If I didn't have to do that, just extracting from `name` to `description` is possible:

```
df["Description"] = df["Name"].str.extract(r"\s(\S+)\s").map({"AAPL":"Apple", "GOOG":"Google"})
```

or extracting the leverage:

```
df["Description"] = df["Name"].str.extract(r"(\d+X)")
```

If possible, I would like to use `regex` to extract the variables, as in reality I will be doing some more detailed regex e.g. for retrieving different formats of multipliers, e.g. `X2`, `2x` and so forth.

**Note**: I perhaps need to set up another column to inform whether the leverage is positive or negative and use that to decide whether to append `"-"` in front of the multiplier as `-10X leverage.`

```
df["direction"] = df["name"].map(lambda x: "Long" if "LONG" in x else "Short" if "SHORT " in x else "Long")

Name                   Direction      Description
"LONG AAPL 2X CBZ"     "Long"         "Tracks Apple with 2X leverage."
"SHORT GOOG 10X VON"   "Short"        "Tracks Google with -10X leverage."
```

Comment: should it not be `"LONG AAPL 2X CBZ"`?

Comment: Thanks, corrected the DataFrame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we only care about the first two and second last substrings:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(["LONG AAPL 2X CBZ", "SHORT GOOG 10X VON", "BULL AXP UN X3 VON","LONG AXP X3 VON"], columns=["Name"])

maps = {"AAPL": "Apple", "GOOG": "Google"}
signs = {"SHORT": "-"}

def split(i):
    spl = i.split()
    a, b, c = spl[0], spl[1], spl[-2]
    val = maps.get(b, b) # if name is not to be replaced keep original
    return "Tracks  {} with {}{} leverage".format(val, signs.get(a, ""), c)

df["Description"]  = df["Name"].map(split)
```

Output:

```
                 Name                        Description
0    LONG AAPL 2X CBZ     Tracks  Apple with 2X leverage
1  SHORT GOOG 10X VON  Tracks  Google with -10X leverage
2  BULL AXP UN X3 VON       Tracks  AXP with X3 leverage
3     LONG AXP X3 VON       Tracks  AXP with X3 leverage
```

Just splitting is a  more efficient than using a regex:

```
In [33]: df2 = pd.concat([df]*10000)
In [34]: timeit  df2["Name"].map(split)
10 loops, best of 3: 57.5 ms per loop

In [35]: timeit f2(df2['Name'])
10 loops, best of 3: 168 ms per loop
```

If you want to add more words to replace just add them to maps and the same with signs.

Comment: This does not properly handle the sign of the leverage as described in the question.

Comment: @abeboparebop, I missed that part but it is pretty trivial to implement

Comment: @PadraicCunningham What if there is more text in between? For `BULL AXP UN X3 VON` I get: `ValueError: too many values to unpack`. Unfortunately this will vary a lot which makes splitting by space difficult.

Comment: @Winterflags, we can use a regex with findall, I will edit, what do you want to happen when you don't have a row with either AAPL or GOOG?

Comment: If possible, just take regex `\s(\S+)\s` and `return` that into the string.

Comment: @Winterflags, not sure I understand, do you want a Nan value of some specific string as the default?

Comment: `\s(\S+)\s` to return the next snippet after LONG/SHORT, so if it's `LONG AXP UN X3 VON`, it shouldn't be substituted by dictionary and pass through `AXP` to the string.

Comment: what should `LONG AXP X3 VON` produce?

Comment: Produce `Tracks  AXP with 3X leverage` if possible. Or if we would've used a dictionary, it would've been `American Express`. But if it's not in there, `AXP`. `UN` and `VON` is omitted.

Comment: what about `BULL AXP UN X3 VON`?

Comment: so really the first two strings and the last two strings are all we care about, are the all either four or five word sentences?

Comment: Hm, yes the first two strings `LONG` and `AAPL`, and the multiplier `X2|2X`. The company name may be variable length, it will however always be after the first `\s`

Comment: Then we can split again! Is the name always a single word?

Comment: Ah, yes if it doesn't matter if the string is LONG AXP X3 VON or LONG AXP UN X3 VON. Or if it would be even more words in there. But generally, the multiplier will always be second last so it should work. The company is always a single word

Comment: Yep, the edit should work, we don't care about what happens in the middle of the string. It is also the most efficient 28ms on a large sample vs 65ms for the regex

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Thanks for that! :) I will try your solution now. Btw, if you're interested in another Pandas question I have a +50 bounty up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30922939/pandas-write-variable-number-of-new-rows-from-list-in-series

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Shouldn't I apply `split` as: `df['Description'] = df['Name'].map(split)` to run it? Or similar

Comment: @Winterflags, yep, forgot that part! I also added some timings

Comment: Great, this works superbly now. Also good thing that it is inclusive of non-dictionary names which the alternative answer wasn't, so I have updated my accepted answer accordingly. Thanks a lot to all who answered, very insightful!

Comment: @Winterflags, no worries, in regard to your other question where are you getting that data from?

Comment: I imagine you can get the prices separately, usually a regex when dealing with html is not a great idea. Anyway if you add how you create the dataframe and provide a toy example of data it I am pretty sure it is trivial to do what you want

Comment: Yes, sure no worries. Or if you can share the webpage that would help

Comment: Not sure where ac_result comes from but if you have adat like that then just split and strip to get names price then pass the list, try this code and see how it works. http://pastebin.com/sPnPZvTr

Answer (score 1):

You can define an explicit function to apply to the entire `Name` Series.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(["LONG AAPL 2X CBZ","SHORT GOOG 10X VON"], columns=["Name"])

dmap = {"AAPL":"Apple", "GOOG":"Google"}
signmap = {"LONG": "", "SHORT": "-"}

def f(strseries):
    company = strseries.str.extract(r"\s(\S+)\s").map(dmap)
    leverage = strseries.str.extract(r"(\d+X)")
    sign = strseries.str.extract(r"(\S+)\s").map(signmap)
    return "Tracks " + company + " with " + sign + leverage + " leverage."

df['Description'] = f(df['Name'])
```

EDIT: this can be sped up by about a factor of 2 doing the regex extractions all at once, at the expense of some readability.

```
def f2(strseries):
    sub_df = strseries.str.extract('(?P<sign>\S+)\s(?P<company>\S+)\s(?P<leverage>\d+X)')
    return "Tracks " + sub_df.company.map(dmap) + " with " + sub_df.sign.map(signmap) + sub_df.leverage + " leverage."

df['Description'] = f2(df['Name'])
```

Comment: I would like to use this solution as regex is a bit more robust for many different situations. But how can I make it write `\s(\S+)\s` as `company` if there is no match in `dmap`? Something like: `val = maps.get(b, b);
    return "Tracks  {} with {}{} leverage".format(val, signs.get(a, ""), c)`